# Change Add to Cart text to "Apply" on WooCommerce single product pages only

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, product

I am using the code below to replace add to cart button with a linked button to the product in Shop, related products and archives pages only

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'shop_view_product_button', 10);
    function shop_view_product_button() {
    global $product;
    $link = $product->get_permalink();
    echo '<a href="' . $link . '" class="button addtocartbutton">View Product</a>';
}
```

But I need to change the add to cart button text on the single product page to "Apply".

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'product_single_add_to_cart_custom_text', 20, 1 );
function product_single_add_to_cart_custom_text( $text ) {
    $text = __( 'Apply', 'woocommerce' );

    return $text;
}
```

Comment: How can we change that text on related products section??

Comment: @LiaqatA. Using `woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text` hook with something like [in this answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77570717/3730754)